# Adverbial usage of “one shot”

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage

I have one question about the better use of this sentence below:

**“Do it with one shot" or " Do it in one shot"**

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: What exactly is being done? You have not provided enough context.

Comment: Are you asking whether one of those two choices is better than the other in certain contexts?

Comment: @Lambie I want to choose the text to be my slogan. And I want to know the difference between that sentence and the right time to choose "With" or "In".

Both these contexts have the same meaning?

Comment: @Chaim Yes exactly, and the right time to choose "With" or "In".

Comment: "Do it with one shot", immediately brings to mind a sport such as basketball, where someone is being goaded to "do it with one shot" of the ball.  "Do it *in* one shot" is more broad, and implies "get the job done on the first try", or possibly "drink the entire amount in a single gulp".

Comment: This is not the purpose of this site. In any event, slogans are for specific things, and there is not enough information.

Comment: For what it's worth, a Google Books search for "do it with one shot" yields [two matches](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=CrHDW5qgNuHs9APG9a-ADA&q=%22do+it+with+one+shot%22&oq=%22do+it+with+one+shot%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...22915.23418.0.26026.4.4.0.0.0.0.74.274.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.74...33i10k1.0.NUDeUM49ICs) ...

Comment: ... and a Google Book search for "do it in one shot" yields [six matches](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=ArHDW5KmJ9XZ9APyhaqYAw&q=%22do+it+in+one+shot%22&oq=%22do+it+in+one+shot%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...2556.5724.0.7701.17.17.0.0.0.0.111.1189.16j1.17.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.381...0.0.r8qVY0tt8M8).

Answer (score 0):

**one shot**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/one+shot) the idiom

> Achieved with or consisting of a single shot, stroke, attempt, etc.;
>   occurring, produced, used, etc., only once; single, isolated.

As in:

> This is a one-shot deal. If we back out now, there's no way we'll get
>   a second chance.

In your examples context is needed to use the idiomatic sense, such as:

> “Here is your chance.  You have one shot"

Comment: also the idiom "in one go"